# Flutter Colored Radio Button

Tags: flutter, button, radio-button, uibutton

in flutter How do I make this type of Colored Radio button?

[image: Colored Radio Button]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create N items with many different widgets like Container, that will represent the circle. And place checkbox only when the item is selected.

```dart
enum ItemColor {
  white(Colors.white),
  red(Colors.red),
  green(Colors.green),
  blue(Colors.blue);

  const ItemColor(this.color);
  final Color color;
}

class _RBSelectionState extends State<RBSelection> {
  ItemColor? selectedItem;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        for (ItemColor item in ItemColor.values)
          ElevatedButton(
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              backgroundColor: item.color,
              shape: const CircleBorder(),
              fixedSize: Size(100, 100),
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                selectedItem = item;
              });
            },
            child: selectedItem == item ? const Icon(Icons.check) : null,
          ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```